# How to access UILabel in custom cell with indexPath and implement user data from array/ dictionary into the label

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary, indexpath

[image: ios simulator]

I have been trying to fix this for 4 days and still no luck so any help would be appreciated. I am trying to create a table view where workers can upload their profiles and users can scroll through to see which ones they like (see simulator photo). However, when I use `indexPath.row` it fills out the whole cell when I only want it to fill out one label so I can configure the different labels with the data I want.

Here is my Table view controller code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

struct Worker {
    var name: String!
    var price: String!
}

class SelectATaskerTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var myList:[String] = []

    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

    var handle: DatabaseHandle!
    var storageHandle: StorageHandle!
    var storageRef: StorageReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.rowHeight = 111

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        handle = ref.child("WorkerProfile").child("Name").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let item = snapshot.value as? String {
                self.myList.append(item)
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

    @IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {
        Database.database().reference().child("WorkerProfile").removeValue()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return myList.count
    }

    var nameText: String!
    var pricePerHourText: String!
    var extraDetailsText: String!
    var profilePicImage: UIImage!

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:MyCellTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MyCellTableViewCell

       cell.firstName.text = myList[indexPath.row]
       cell.pricePerHour.text = myList[indexPath.row]

      // cell.extraDetails.text = extraDetailsText
      // cell.profilePic.image = profilePicImage
      // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
```

And my custom table view cell code

```
import UIKit

class MyCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pricePerHour: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var extraDetails: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var profilePic: UIImageView!
}
```

Comment: You are using an array of `String` (`[String]`) as data source, that means one string per row. If you want to display more data in a row you have to use a struct like `Worker` as data source (`[Worker]`) and get more attributes from the database.

Comment: thank you! how do i change the data source to the worker instead of string???

Comment: Just change the type to `[Worker]`, in `viewWillAppear` get a record from the database rather than a single attribute and append a `Worker` instance.

Comment: and what about the handle as it only lets me download one child path at a time? do you think you could show me the code in an answer???

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Firebase.

Comment: oh okay, thanks for your help anyway!!